# "Type" of a function template?

Tags: type-theory

In C++ a simple function like

```
int id_int(int x){return x;}
```

has type `id_int :: int->int`
a class template like

```
template<class T>
class List<T>{...};
```

has kind `List :: *->*`

But what is the type or kind of a function template like

```
template<class T>
T id(T x){return x;}
```

Could it be `id :: \x. x->x`? Does this even make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function like `T id(T x){return x;}` is actually a [(parametrically) polymorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism), and there are many frameworks that allow assigning a type to such beasts.

One of the most popular frameworks to talk about such things is [system F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F), which allows expressing the type of the above statement as: $$\forall T:*.\ T\rightarrow T$$

This requires the ability to *quantify over types* to form other types, which is the main feature of system F. Note that because `id` is a *value*, it's type has itself a *kind*, that is
$$\forall T:*.\ T\rightarrow T\ \ :\ \ * $$

in keeping with the analogy with `List`, whose kind is, as you noted, $*\rightarrow *$, which makes it a *type constructor*.

Note also that the `List` type constructor is not a term in system F, for that you need to go further out to system ${F}_\omega$, which was designed in part to study how polymorphism and type constructors may interact.

Comment: CS is the appropriate place for these kinds of questions, I think, unless they are really specific to the concrete programing language used (in which case, stackoverflow can actually help!). CS theory should only be used for *research level* questions (but there is a very large overlap of users, so asking here is usually a good bet even for those).

Comment: Note that this answer does *not* apply to C++ since C++ doesn't respect parametricity at all. This means a function with a template "type" like `template <class T> T f(T x)` doesn't even have to be type correct when instantiated to a concrete type, e.g. `template <class T> T f(T x) { return x + x; }` won't work when instantiated to a class that doesn't overload `+`.

Comment: That is absolutely true @DerekElkins, I tried to answer the *spirit* of the question since, in C++, everything is too horrible to be called computer *science*.